# Doctrine2 create new query inside another's iteration breaks loop

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to fetch some results inside a cursor iteration, so I get related elements and stuff. But when executing this query inside the iteration, the iteration cursor die and the iteration will end even if there's more data to get.

An example

```
protected $em;
public function __construct() {
    $this->em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
}
public function getProducts() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products"; // 100 Products
    $stmt = $this->select($query);

    while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
        // This breaks the cursor so only 1 product is parsed.
        // If I remove this line, iteration ends perfectly (100 products)
        $pictures = $this->getPictures($result['id']);
    }
}
public function getPictures($product) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE product_id = :product_id";
    $stmt = $this->select($query, array('product_id' => $product));
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
public function select($query, array $params = array()) {
    $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot use another cursor without closing the previous one.
If you look the ResullStatement interface:

```
/**
 * Closes the cursor, enabling the statement to be executed again.
 *
 * @return boolean TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
public function closeCursor();
```

When a cursor is closed, usually the stmt memory is frees. 
So, why not write just one single query for that? You can use a subquery to extract all the products id.
Something like:

Select * from picture p where p.id IN (select pr.id from products pr)`

Comment: Yeah that was my second choice, but I was trying to avoid because I want the code be friendly and I need separated methods because they can be called from anywhere, actually I'm using `fetchAll()` to avoid cursor overlapping until I figure out another way.

Comment: Yep that could be another solution. Anyway, if you put that code in a repository, let me say PictureRepository, what is more code friendly than a method called "getPicturesInProducts($product_ids)". The database (i.e the Rpository) is an abstraction.